# Android accelerometer injecting data

Tags: android, accelerometer, device, code-injection

I have a problem, I need to simulate an accelerometer on real Android device. I can simulate touchscreen or HW keys with /dev/input/eventX but I cannt do that with accelerometer because real sensor still push date in that file. Do you have any idea how handle this?

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/openintents/sensorsimulator) may help you

Comment: I've already tried this, but it only shows sensors's values with no effect on device. I thought it is ok because the simulator is for emulated android isnt it?

Comment: Maybe if you tell which is the main function of the app we could think another idea

Comment: I don't develop application, I need to test it but I have only .apk file, so I can't simulate it in source. So I think I need to use accelerometer for testing to send information to app that device is inclined and see if its behavior is properly.

Comment: I know that it is not the best solution (but the only I have) but what about using the emulator+sensorsimulator to test the apk?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do really faithful testing for SM-T530 and some other models where is neccessary to use real device.